# ubuntu - reserve storage space for operating system

Tags: linux, storage

twice this past month that on two different servers, our / partition ran out of storage.
the main problem (for me at least) with space running out, is the system locking down. lvextend for example will not work until some files are deleted to free up space for the OS.

is there a way to reserve storage space for the OS, so I don't have any core system commands malfunctioning (like the example above with lvextend)?

P.S- 
obviously, monitoring is a big part of preventing this situation. unfortunately we cannot always rely on it, so I am searching for more of a fail-proof solution..

--- edit ---
due to some correct comments, I would like to clarify: User data should obviously be stored on a separate partition (though regrettably I don't always follow this rule). I was referring specifically on how to avoid application data and etc. from overflowing the system partition.

Comment: Exactly what is consuming the space? Log files? Some temporary files? Database? I'm just thinking that one way to at least try to prevent your problem is to make sure you have automatic deletion / compression of old log files and so on properly configured. Do you?

Comment: Users can't log in properly and your system starts to fail in interesting ways when you completely run out of disk space. When you create multiple partitions (or LVM volumes) with separate file-systems you can assign hard reserved disk space for the OS and keep that separate from the area's where users and/or specific applications are allowed to write (eg `/home` `/tmp/`  `/var/tmp/` `/var/spool/` `/oradata/` etc.) , mitigating operational risk of badly behaved users and/or applications.

Comment: one time it was .net core sdk that took the space. the other time it was docker volumes (on a test machine- the reason it wasn't partitioned to a separate volume).

Comment: obviously user data (docker for example) should be separated- I am particularly searching for a way to avoid from the OS to cripple itself with logs or application data

Comment: @HBruijn, that is a great suggestion. is there a complete list of these directory with the typical size they should be allocated? it is possible to change the partitioning easily also after the OS was installed?

Comment: For flexibility use LVM (and don't allocate all space immediately but keep some unassigned to be able to quickly increase a certain volume / file-system). Which directories are useful to mount on a separate file`system and how big that should be depends on your workload, my `/var/lib/mysql` may need to be a lot larger than your /var/lib/postgresl/data`

Answer (score 1):

That's what partitioning is for.

Mount your data directory on a separate partition. Even when the data partition fills up the system will still be usable.

With LVM, use separate volumes.